# Tomcat6 and MySQL issues

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have a new installation of Ubuntu 11.10 server with Tomcat6.  I am using Eclipse Indigo to make a Java Servlet that pulls data from my MySQL server.  I have placed the latest Connector/J (mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar) in my servers CATALINA_HOME/lib directory.  In Eclipse I make a Dynamic Web Project to which I then create a servlet.  The Java code for the servlet is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestServlet
 */
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public TestServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Context initCtx = null;
    try {
        initCtx = new InitialContext();
    } catch (NamingException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    Context envCtx = null;
    try {
        envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    } catch (NamingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    DataSource ds = null;
    try {
        ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Statement stat = null;
    try {
        stat = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("in");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

I have the following in my WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>TestDB</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I had to create the context.xml in META-INF, but here is the context of my META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="myuser" password="mypass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1"/>
</Context>
```

I export to a war, deploy to my tomcat server.   When I browse to the servlet I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:67)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Line 67 of TestServlet.java is the conn.createStatement(); line.  Sorry my code is messy, I went with individual try catch blocks because I don't get this error when I do one big try catch, though it still does not connect to the MySQL database.  I'm sure I am missing a rather simple step here, but I can't seem to find it anywhere, I'm a bit of a newb with Tomcat and Servlets.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: I realize the code posted above is executing `system.out.println("in")` instead of the printwriter, the error is the same, I rushed that part of my code when presenting this question, it should be irrelevant.

Comment: Check to make sure your context.xml is actually being deployed; if you're using the WTP plugin you need to enable publishing of module contexts.

Comment: So is there a stacktrace from getConnection()?

Comment: verify that you have created the database "test1" on the server too with the correct username and password. this is the database that you point to in the url in your resource.

Comment: Maybe I should specify.  I am developing in Eclipse on a Windows machine.  I am Exporting my project as a .war, which does contain the context.xml file, and tomcat does explode this file and place the context.xml file appropriately as far as I can tell.  @DaveNewton, does enabling publishing of module contexts still pertain if I am not deploying the code by "Run on server"?  For testing purposes I set up a tomcat server on my windows machine, changed the host url in context.xml to the ip of my mysql server, deployed locally by "Run as server" and the code runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in my `/etc/mysql/my.conf`.  I had set my bind-address to the ip address of the server, this was causing the inability for Tomcat to connect.  Why Tomcat can't but PHP can is beyond me, but whatever.  I changed my bind-address to 0.0.0.0 and all is well.

Comment: At any given time, there are multiple interfaces active. One of these is "lo"; the loopback interface where the 127.0.0.1 address is bound. Another will be something like "eth0" or "wlan0" (linux) or "Local Lan Connection" or "Wireless Network Connection" (windows). When you set the bind address for MySQL you were, in effect, saying "only use the interface that has this address." The 0.0.0.0 address say to bind to "all interfaces."

Comment: Why would PHP successfully connect to the mysql server when given localhost?

Comment: The PHP MySQL client is being "clever." When you tell it to use localhost, it actually connects to the local named-pipe (windows) or unix domain socket (linux). See the first note here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Tomcat 6 context docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html):

> Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> - Only if a context file does not exist for the application in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/, in an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files. If the web application is packaged as a WAR then /META-INF/context.xml will be copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to match the application's context path. Once this file exists, it will not be replaced if a new WAR with a newer /META-INF/context.xml is placed in the host's appBase.

Try deleting the copy in Tomcat's `conf` dir and see if your `context.xml` file is then picked up.

Comment: I just achieved success by changing localhost in the context.xml to the actual ip address of the server.  I have no clue why localhost and 127.0.0.1 won't work for me, the problem must be in MySQL user permissions.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tdramble Oh; huh. Weird. Okay, I'll delete this answer to avoid throwing people off. You should add that as an answer, then accept it, so others know what the solution was!

Comment: I just submitted my answer, I will accept it in 2 days when I am permitted.